# Northern Ireland open source raster?

Tags: united-kingdom, data

Does anyone know if there is any open source data downloads for Northern Ireland, seems not as straight forward as rest of UK?

Comment: Do you have any requirements for the imagery (i.e. resolution, collection frequency, etc.)?

Comment: well just a 250k raster would do at moment...

Comment: I couldn't find a good source, but the 'satellite imagery' section of this page might be a good place to start: http://libguides.ucd.ie/gisguide/FindSpatialData

Comment: OSNI do not do Opendata as OSGB (England, Wales and Scotland) you can buy OSNI digital products here http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/index/information-and-services/property-and-housing/your-neighbourhood-roads-and-streets/ordnance-survey-of-northern-ireland/product-range/digital-products.htm or use OpenStreetMap

Comment: tweet sent to OSNI https://twitter.com/mapperz/status/592751165974142977

Comment: Rasters can be many things, not just imagery. And "open source data downloads" is pretty broad. Are you looking for aerial/satellite imagery? What does "250k raster" mean? Is that a file size, a resolution, some sort of scale? Are you looking for Ordinance Survey OpenData, or just free data in general?

Comment: OSNI likely to be releasing some opendata in the near future see the reply https://twitter.com/osni_maps/status/593067727805390848